# In SSRS what is the correct way to change a date from the standard "d" offered in the properties to a custom one?

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, format

I have a date as shown in expression:

= Fields!last_sales_date.Value

will show: 04/16/2010

Applying standard date properties allows only a few ways to display this date. I don't want to use the system dates supplied.

What is the correct way to customize the display format to the following:

Want to show: 4/16/10

Using VS 2003

Answer (score 2):

SSRS uses VB.net so you can use Format

[Formatting Numbers and Dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157406.aspx) (SSRS) which links to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(VS.95).aspx). These are the same for all versions 2000-> 2008. I assume SSRS 2000 if using VS 2003.

So "M/d/yy" looks a good candidate

Answer (score 0):

=FormatDateTime(Fields!last_sales_date.Value,2)

change the 2 to different values to get different formats

Answer (score 0):

Pick your textbox goto properties and in the format property just add a .net format such as:

MM/dd/yy